# Is it possible to use @EmbeddedId with @IdClass

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
//@IdClass(CityId.class)
public class City implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private Location location;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "citycode", nullable = false)
    private String cityCode;

    @Column(name="countrycode" ,insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Embeddable
    public static class Location implements Serializable {
        @Column(name="latitude",nullable = false)
        private BigDecimal latitude;
        @Column(name="longitude",nullable = false)
        private BigDecimal longitude;

        public Location(BigDecimal latitude, BigDecimal longitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

    }
```

When I run the application I get this error
This class [class com.*.entity.City] does not define an IdClass

So I enabled @IdClass(CityId.class) , but didn't remove @EmbeddedId for location.

and my Id class is like this

```
public class CityId {
private String cityCode;
private City.Location location;

public CityId(String cityCode, City.Location location) {
    this.cityCode = cityCode;
    this.location = location;
}
// --- equlas , hashcode()
```

I get this error :

Could not locate field name [latitude] on class [com.*.entity.City]

To Resolve this I have to remove @EmbeddedId and @Embedded from the Entiy and define the longitude and latitude column.

But countryCode is a foreign key, and latitude and longitude are composite primary keys in the table

```
CREATE TABLE city (
name varchar2(25) not null,
Lattitude DECIMAL(10) not null,
longitude DECIMAL(10) not null, 
countryCode varchar2(3) not null,
 CONSTRAINT  loc_pk
 PRIMARY KEY(latitude,longitude),
 CONSTRAINT countrycode_fk 
 FOREIGN KEY(countryCode) 
 REFERENCES country(iso3)
);
```

If I do not use @Id with countryCode it will not let me use it as a foreign key.

My question is what should I use

1. @EmbeddedId approach
2. @IdClass
3. Or is there any other approach so that I don't have to composite my foreign keys with primary key

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@EmbeddedId` approach. You can't mix that with `@IdClass`